# Getting json response from threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading

```
    def access(Token, number,engine,gateway):
        response = requests.Session()   
        response.mount(engine, gateway) 
        headers = {'Host': 'www.google.com',       
                   'Authorization': 'bearer %s' % (Token),
                   'Content-type': 'application/json'}

        url = 'https://www google.com'
        data = '{"code":"'+ str("".join(random.choice('0123456789')for i in range(4))) +'","countrycode":"1","countryid":"0","mobile":"%s"}' % (number)                  
        response = response.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)                              
        print(response.json()['result']['displaymessage'])

# ==================================================================================================================    
def verify(Token, number):
 engine = 'https://www.google com'
 gateway = ApiGateway(engine, access_key_id="0", access_key_secret="0")
 gateway.start()        
 response = requests.Session()
 response.mount(engine, gateway)            
 headers = {'Host': 'www.google.com',      
            'Authorization': 'bearer %s' % (Token),
            'Content-type': 'application/json'}
            
 url = 'https://www.google.com'
 data = '{"code":"'+ str("".join(random.choice('0123456789')for i in range(4))) +'","countrycode":"1","countryid":"0","mobile":"%s"}' % (number)    
 response = response.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)  

 if __name__ == "__main__": 
  for _ in range(9999999):
   if response.status_code != 200 or response.json()['result']['displaymessage'] == 'Verification not successed.':    
    processThread = threading.Thread(target=brute, args=[Token,number,engine,gateway])
    processThread.start()   
    usleep(50000)   
   else:
    print("\n" + "#Notice =", response.json()['result']['displaymessage'] + "\n")     
    gateway.shutdown()
    break
```

Im trying to multithread a function if response in json is Verification not successed but then i want to break the loop if i got another response .. i tried multi things but it wont need to break the loop is there any solution to get that code work as i need

Comment: Have you actually tried running that code? *response* doesn't exist so it will fail immediately upon entering the first *for* loop. Are you sure that displaymessage will ever be equal to 'Verification not successed'?

Comment: @vlad yes its an example as i using aws gateways to establish the connection so icant post my keys on public

Comment: I need to get the response from access function then break the loop in that access function

Comment: You miss my point. Your code is simply not runnable